# how to remove an image path from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I'm installing a wordpress theme, there is an image link path that is not found but still work even then upload a new images nothing shown, i want to know if there is any method to remove the path link from page.

Comment: if you want to remove the local server image path?

Comment: yes from code page

Answer (score 0):

If the theme contains this path in a hardcoded way, you should ask the developer to fix it and update the theme.

**OR:** Create a child theme and look inside the theme files for the file with the wrong URL and fix it by yourself.

[Click here for more info on child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: I'm already using the child theme but ,i don't how to use functions on it please can you help me

Comment: You don't need to add a function, just find the file with the URL in the main theme and copy it to your child theme (under the same path). There, inside the copy, you can change the URL.